# Вывод параметров с помощью json на Swift

Tags: ios, swift, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте. Не получается получить отдельные параметры при запросе к API вконтакте на Swift. Получаю набор значений, пробую с помощью json выводить отдельные параметры, но выдает ошибку. Подскажите, что я делаю неправильно?

```
var params = ["user_ids":"896232"] as Dictionary <String, String>
let request:VKRequest = VKRequest(method: "users.get", andParameters: params, andHttpMethod: "GET" )
request.executeWithResultBlock({ (response) -> Void in
    let books: AnyObject! = response.json
    println(books.objectForKey("id"))
}, errorBlock: {
    (error) -> Void in
    println("error")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Уже разобрался. Кому интересно, то вот мое решение этой задачи:

```
request.executeWithResultBlock({ (response) -> Void in
    let books =  response.json as NSArray
    if let theTitle: AnyObject = books[0].objectForKey("photo_100") {
        println(theTitle)
    }}, errorBlock: {
        (error) -> Void in
        println("error")
})
```